# How to open new window below _all_ other windows?

Tags: window-splitting

Suppose my Emacs frame looks like this:

```
.-------------.
|a     |b     |
|      |      |
|      |      |
|      |------|
|      |c     |
|      |      |
|      |      |
'-------------'
```

Is is possible now to open another window below *all* other windows to get the frame that looks like the one below?

```
.-------------.
|a     |b     |
|      |      |
|      |------|
|      |c     |
|      |      |
|-------------|
|d            |
'-------------'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
(split-window (frame-root-window) (truncate (* (window-total-height (frame-root-window)) 0.75)) 'below)
```

The crucial part is `(frame-root-window)` which returns a window spanning the whole frame.

Comment: TIL frame-root-window - thanks!

Comment: Maybe `window-total-height` should be called with a WINDOW argument (probably the root window): as it stands, the size is dependent on the currently selected window.

Comment: Good call, fixed.